# `syntax error, unexpected '='`

Tags: php, syntax, while-loop

this code give me a syntax error (`syntax error, unexpected '='`) in this line:

```
$num.$i++ = $form[$val];
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$i=0;
while ($sql -> fetch()) {
    $num.$i++ = $form[$val]; // error here
    echo ($num0);
}
```

i want an output similar to:

```
$num0 =$form[$val];
$num1 =$form[$val];
$num2 =$form[$val];
and so on...
```

thanks

Comment: What is $num.$i++? $ is the prefix for a variable in PHP, you cannot use it to access data members of an object of hash map/ array. Did you mean to use $num.i/ $num["i"] or $num[i]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

---

```
${'num'.$i++}
```

---

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct, the simpliest way is usage of array:

```
$i=0;
$num = array();
while ($sql -> fetch()) {
    $num[$i] = $form[$val];
    echo $num[$i];

    $i++;
}
```

After this, you will have $num[0], $num[1], ... and you can use it as you need (the `echo` does not need to be there.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion, but the answer still needs work before being recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art18915.asp